# Proof of continuous symmetry breaking

Tags: thermodynamics, symmetry-breaking

My question concerns how to show/explain the existence of spontaneous symmetry.
I will lay out a seeming paradox, preporting to show no symmetry breaking is possible.
I understand the resolution for a discrete symmetry, however, the resolution for a continuous symmetry is not clear to me.

Given a system with some symmetry $G$, for example a set of $N$ scalar fields $\varphi_i(x)$ and a free energy $F$ invariant under rotations $g \in G = \mathrm{O}(N)$, the system is said to have undergone spontaneous symmetry breaking if $\langle\varphi_i\rangle = (0, 0, ... \bar\varphi, 0, ...) \neq \vec 0$.
However, assuming the system is an equilibrium one, the probability distribution is given by the Boltzmann weight $e^{-\beta F}$.
Now, $\varphi_i = (0, ...\bar \varphi, ...)$ and $ (0,  ... -\bar \varphi, ...)$ are connected by an element of $\mathrm{O}(N)$, and thus their probability are equal as $F$ and thus $e^{-\beta F}$ is invariant under such a shift.
This means that, naïvley, a sum over all configurations weighted by probability must give $\langle \varphi_i \rangle = 0$, no matter the parameters such as temperature or dimension, excluding the possibility of spontaneous symmetry breaking.

This paradox is, to my understanding, solved in the discrete symmetry case by considering an external field, adding a therm $h_i\varphi_i$ to the free energy, and thus explicitly breaking the symmetry. In the thermodynamic limit, the ``magnetization'' $\langle\varphi_i\rangle$ will be discontinuous in the vanishing external field limit.
This indicates spontaneous symmetry breaking.
The zero field limit and the thermodynamic limit do not commute.

The mistake done in the naïve summation was to assume that the system is still fully ergodic.
We assumed that, given the system is prepared in one of the broken states, it could reach the other symmetry-broken state via thermal fluctuations.
In the thermodynamic limit, the probability of these fluctuations vanish and the two degenerate vacua are isolated.
This is discussed in the context of quantum field theory in Weinberg's book, ``The Quantum Theory of Fields'', vol 2., chapter 19.
The overlap between the degenerate vacuum states vanishes in the infinite volume limit.

Is there a similar resolution in the case of continuous symmetry?
This seems more difficult, as by definition, the degenerate vacua are connected and there is thus no need to pass over an energy barrier to access them.
How can you show that a continuous symmetry is spontaneously broken?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, Weinberg's proof is not restricted to discrete symmetry.

Comment: Well, in 19.1 he chooses reflection symmetry to talk about. Maybe it generalizes, but it is not obvious to me that it does.